# how to parse Unicode xml data with encoding header declare

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I have a xml str which `encoding` header declare as `gb2312`, I want to parse it with `lxml.parse` and use xpath to get value, the `xml` str content contain `unicode` character, currently my works as below:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import BytesIO

xml_data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="GB2312"?>
<CHARGEINFO>
    <ITEM>
        <DETAILEDCHARGESID>5E8C4E14E9C711EBB56E00155D96E1E0</DETAILEDCHARGESID>
        <UNIT>元</UNIT>
        <CHARGENUM>1</CHARGENUM>
        <CHARGEDATE>2021-07-13 14:18:47</CHARGEDATE>
        <CHARGESTATE>0</CHARGESTATE>
    </ITEM>
</CHARGEINFO>"""
xml_root = etree.parse(BytesIO(xml_data.encode())).getroot()
xml_root.xpath("/CHARGEINFO/ITEM")
```

the output error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/gui/Documents/workspace/PIS_middle_layer/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-11-527d4b9dab58>", line 14, in <module>
    xml_root = etree.parse(BytesIO(xml_data.encode())).getroot()

  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3521, in lxml.etree.parse

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseDocument

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1896, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1784, in lxml.etree._parseDoc

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1141, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 615, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 725, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 654, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError

  File "<string>", line 1
XMLSyntaxError: switching encoding: encoder error, line 1, column 38
```

Is there any better way to parse this xml data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared the XML to be encoded in `gb2312`, but `BytesIO(xml_data.encode())` defaults to encoding in `utf8`, hence the "switching encoding" error.  The declaration and the encoding of the data need to agree.

Change the `xml_root` assignment line to:

```
xml_root = etree.parse(BytesIO(xml_data.encode('gb2312'))).getroot()
```

OR change the `xml_data` assignment line to:

```
xml_data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```